# How to graft a remote branch?

Tags: git

The setup for this question requires some careful wording.

Start from the simplest possible repository: one single commit (which could be empty, if you want).

From this original one-commit repo, make two separate clones, in `/path/to/repo1` and `/path/to/repo2`, respectively.  Now imagine that each of these two clones, independently from the other one, evolves as a simple linear history.

If `A` is the single commit in the original repository at the time of cloning `repo1` and `repo2`, the situation could look something like this:

```
repo1:

A-----B-----C-----D-----E-----F-----G-----H-----I-----J-----K-----L


repo2:

A-----M-----N-----O-----P-----R-----S-----T-----U-----V
```

Now I want to combine both clones so that the resulting commit graph looks like this:

```
   ,--B-----C-----D-----E-----F-----G-----H-----I-----J-----K-----L
  /
 A
  \
   `--M-----N-----O-----P-----R-----S-----T-----U-----V
```

I've tried many tacks, but I never get a graph like the one above...

Comment: Write what you have tried.  Did you try https://metacpan.org/module/git-stitch-repo?

Answer (score 3):

This works for me without any hacks:

```
git clone -o repo1 path/to/repo1 target
cd target
git remote add repo2 path/to/repo2
git fetch repo2
git branch master2 repo2/master
```

At this point, you will have 2 local branches: `master` tracking `repo1/master`, and `master2` tracking `repo2/master`.

If you `git log master`, it will look like `L`, `K`, `J`, ..., `C`, `B`, **`A`**.

If you `git log master2`, it will look like `V`, `U`, `T`, ..., `N`, `M`, **`A`**.

Comment: Why would those branches share any history after your commands?

Comment: Well, because this is how git works? If you don't trust me, try it out - I have.

Comment: nope, this is not how git works – you will just have to branches that don’t touch each other at all. If you ran the commands you listed with two repos that are not forks of each other, run this: `git merge-base master master2`. That will output the first commit both branches have in common, which in this case will be nothing.

Comment: Of course I assumed that `repo1` and `repo2` were both forked from the same original repo with commit `A` in it (this is what stated in question if you re-read it). And in this case it works as I described. Try it yourself if you don't believe me

Answer (score 0):

Looks not so difficult.

At first, there must be two branches if you want to combine them into one repo.

And just push clone1 into remote called, branch1

And push clone2 into remote called, branch2

Later, return to a any repo and fetch the latest code.

Br,
Tim